# Risks from network steganography

Tags: network, steganography

I happened to learn that there is an actively researched IT-security field named network steganography. Could experts give a short overview of the current state of affairs, especially about the extent of risks therefrom as well as the counter-measures already being taken and also about eventually feasible usages of the techniques there for beneign purposes by the common people?

[Addendum] I just found a new book: W. Mazurczk et al. (Eds.), Information Hiding in Communication Networks. Wiley, 2016.

Comment: Can you link to any sources that you have read about this new thing? If it is new, assume few people here would know about it.

Comment: It would also help if you included the research you have already done.

Comment: Aren't the risks for steganography basically the same independent of the actual method used? The risk is that somebody can smuggle information past firewalls and content filters. It means that malware in your network might communicate in a way you wouldn't notice.

Comment: @schroeder: I first came to that issue via https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.0917 Since I barely have knowledge in network protocols, my understanding of it is correspondingly low. A newer reference I found is arxiv.org/abs/1407.2029